# Can not cast from source type to destination type

Tags: c#, polymorphism, downcast

I am writing a game in Unity, and I am trying to use polymorphism to access 2 subclasses but keep getting an error:

> Can not cast from source type to destination type

I have a serialized list of `Places`, and I am trying to downcast to a `Property`, which is a subclass of `Place`. How am I able to do this in Unity?

```
((Property)Board.GetBoardPlace(Players[PlayerTurn].Position)).Owner = Players[PlayerTurn];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [downcast and upcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast)

Comment: For what you're doing in code, the cast is probably unnecessary. Can you share more of the code and/or reason for the cast? Also, this isn't really a Unity question, so I'm going to remove that tag and tag it C# instead...

Answer (score 0):

If the items in your list of type `Place` were originally instantiated using the base type `Place`, then [I don't think you can/should downcast (or rather, do type conversion) in this manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124336/a-way-of-casting-a-base-type-to-a-derived-type), at least not in a managed language like C#. Consider redesigning, or instantiate as items as type `Property` when populating your list:

```cs
List<Place> Places = new List<Place>();
Places.Add(new Property());
```

Then later, you can cast them to type `Property` when you need to use them:

```cs
Property property = Places[0] as Property;
if (property != null){
    // Conversion successful
}
```

You can read a bit more on this in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The problem is that the items are Dropped in the editor. Although the items are of type Property, there is no place in the code where I  instantiate them. If it was done int he code using ... new Property() i think I would be fine but since I am trying to drop a dynamic board from the editor there is no way to do that. I thought dragging a Property type in the editor would be equivalent but it is not.