# C# - Inherited method passing self object

Tags: c#

The real problem comes up with Reflection and assembly patching/hooking. I'll put a simple example to show up my question without being too hard to understand the main problem.

So let's imagine I have these basic classes :

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name;
    public string Price;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Main.Test(this);
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int Wheels;
    public int Doors;
}
```

And on the main code I run this up :

```
public class Main
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Car testCar = new Car()
        {
            Name = "Test Car",
            Price = "4000",
            Wheels = 4,
            Doors = 4
        };

        testCar.DoSomething();
    }

    public static void Test(Vehicle test)
    {
        // Is this allowed ?
        Car helloWorld = (Car) test;
    }   
}
```

Okay, the question is :

Is that cast allowed (in the static method Test) ? Will I lose the Car properties but keep the Vehicle ones ?

In case it's wrong, is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: "In case it's wrong, is there any other way to do it ?" To do what?

Comment: see downcasting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That should be something which is relatively easy to test. So have you tried it? If not, that's kind of a prerequisite to asking a question. If you have, is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: @IvanStoev To get the object as a Car and not as a Vehicle.

Comment: What if it's a `Truck`? I mean, imagine you have another class `Truck : Vehicle`, how do you know that `Vehicle test` is `Car` and not `Truck` or any other `Vehicle` derived class

Comment: I understand that but the real problem i'm facing happens to be this :

I have a LightAttachment component which has a property that references the BaseWeapon but only RangedWeapons (which derive from BaseWeapon) have the Light component, so I know 100% it must be a RangedWeapon.

Therefore, I cast the BaseWeapon to RangedWeapon.

The code is from a game made in Unity (not by me), i'm just modding some parts through patching the IL code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast of `Vehicle` to `Car` is allowed only when the object passed in happens to be `Car`. Otherwise you get an exception.

There is a cast that does not cause exceptions when the type is wrong:

```
Car car = test as Car;
```

This will never throw, but when `Vehicle` is *not* a `Car`, variable `car` would be `null`. You could add an `if` condition to test that the cast has succeeded:

```
Car car = test as Car;
if (car != null) {
    ...
}
Bus bus = test as Bus;
if (bus != null) {
    ...
}
Rv rv = test as Rv;
if (rv != null) {
    ...
}
```

However, C# offers an even better solution: method overloading lets you avoid casting altogether.

```
public class Main {
    public static void Test(Car test) {
        ... // This method will be called by Main.Test(this) of a Car
    }
    public static void Test(Bus test) {
        ... // This method will be called by Main.Test(this) of a Bus
    }
    public static void Test(Rv test) {
        ... // This method will be called by Main.Test(this) of an Rv
    }
}
```

This works, because the compiler knows the exact type of `this` variable when you make the `Main.Test(this)` call.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cast is allowed, and you will not "lose" any properties. But if `Vehicle test` is not, in fact, an instance of `Car` then your cast will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed. It's named [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting).

Remember it is possible to check through type introspection to determine whether the type of the referenced object is indeed the one being cast to or a derived type of it.