# ASP MVC - Model is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null

I am trying to get an integer value from my controller to my view, and then adding that value as a Hidden Field to be used later in my JavaScript client-code.

I am getting an exception while trying to add the hidden field.

Here is the steps to reproduce:

**My cshtml page:**

```
@model Int32 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetGeneric";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section DetailJavascript
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Generic.js")
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model, new { id = "GenericID" });

<h2>GetGeneric</h2>
```

**And here is my Controller code:**

```
public ActionResult GetCategoryDetail(int id)
        {

            Object p = id;

            return View(p);   //I added a breakpoint here and the value of variable 'p' is not null !! 
        }
```

EDIT:
**Exception Details**

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What exception? And why are you passing `object` instead of `int` (should be just `return View(id);`

Comment: Why are you upcasting `id`?

Comment: I have to use object class to use that view constructor @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Up casting? What do you mean? Int  is int32

Comment: What do you see after runnig you app I mean how page source looks like? Maybe try to use <input type='hidden'... /> instead HiddenFor - I've some issues with HiddenFor and sometimes best solutions was to use <input ../>

Comment: you are expecting an Int32 but you are sending an Object, I don't think the conversion could be done automatically. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast

Comment: @IoanaStoian thank you, but I already tried before using "@model Object"  and still throws the exception, weird stuff

Comment: Don't use `@Html.HiddenFor` and then specify an `id` - just use `<input type='hidden'` or `@Html.Hidden(`

Comment: I'm pretty sure (not checked, please correct me if I'm wrong) when you use `HiddenFor` it gets the property name from the `model => model.property`.  As you're not specifying a property, the property name is null, giving you 'Value cannot be null or empty'

Comment: The issue is that your model is a value type and you cannot use a value type as the `TModel` in `public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(...` You need to wrap the property in a model, or generate the html manually

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke ! That what I was expecting, thank you so much for your good explanation! So MVC Model only works with custom classes? That's good to know, kinda a limitation imho...

Comment: FYI, the error is throw in the first line of the `private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(...` method - refer [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs) ( at bottom of page). You could write your won extension method to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @freedomn-m , I think you were right.
Anyway I would like to know how to use HiddenFor with Model as Single Object (string/int), because if I use  I can't dynamycally set the id right? because it's not an asp control but an html one.

I got it fixed using the following solution (I was trying to avoid a Model Class, because I really just the single int/string id attribute).

**CSHTML**

```
@model MyNameSpace.Models.FrontendModel 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.categoryId, new { id = "DetailCategoryId" });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GetCategoryDetail(int id)
{
    return View(new FrontendModel() { categoryId = id});
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class FrontendModel
{
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

PS: If anyone knows how to use single object (string or int) has model please explain me, I would really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your hidden field code to it works with **object as model**

```
@Html.Hidden("GenericID",Model==null?string.Empty:Model.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

DarkLink I suppose it is your `[GET]` Action, so does `id` have some value when it's executing? I think it should look like this:

```
public ActionResult GetCategoryDetail(int id = 0)
{
   return View(id);   
}
```

Then if you do not set `id` by yourself it'll always will be `0` and you don't have `null` exception.

Comment: Read question.. I added breakpoint, id has value... thank you

Comment: Value of 'p' but do the same without up casting to Object, just return View(id)