# create a variable of derived class to refer an object of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, new-operator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public virtual bool DoSomething() { return false; }
    }

    public class Bar : Foo
    {
        public override bool DoSomething() { return true; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Bar test = new Foo();
            Console.WriteLine(test.DoSomething());
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication12.Foo' to 'ConsoleApplication12.Bar'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    ConsoleApplication12    C:\Users\chliu\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication12\ConsoleApplication12\Program.cs

It seems "create a variable of derived class to refer an object by base class" is not allowed. Why?

Comment: this is downcast-and-upcast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work without a cast :

```
Bar test = (Bar)new Foo();
```

Other way around it is working:

```
Foo test = new Bar();
```

It is because a `Bar` can have things that a `Foo` doesn't and it would result into an unexpected behavior if you try to access these on the `Bar` object created from a `Foo`.

To be a little more explicit, you can ask yourself a question to understand better casting:

Is `Foo` a `Bar`? If yes, then the cast from `Foo` to `Bar` will work like in the following example:

```
Foo actuallyBar = new Bar();

Bar = (Bar)actuallyBar; //this will succeed because actuallyBar is actually a Bar
```

The other way of casting will always work because everytime you are asking if the Bar is a Foo the answer will be yes!

```
Foo foo = new Bar();//didn't even had to use explicit cast, because the compiler knows that Bar is a Foo
```

Comment: +1 for intuitive explanation of why one way works without problems and the other way needs  a cast to tell the compiler that the programmer takes full responsibility for any problems down the line.

Comment: When using "Bar test = (Bar)new Foo();", message : InvalidCastException was unhandled -  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ConsoleApplication12.exe" shows.

Comment: @MikeLiu this is normal, you should consider that downcasting will not always succed. If you want to avoid the exception, you can do `Foo test = new Bar() as Foo;` and then if the cast does not succeed, `test` will be `null`.

Comment: @meJustAndrew can you explain more on the "It is because a Bar can have things that a Foo doesn't and it would result into an unexpected behavior if you try to access these on the Bar object created from a Foo."? Is it focused on error message? thank you.

Comment: @MikeLiu you can tell me if know is more clear, and if not, I can improve it.